# Laravel: belongsTo() relation assume one-to-many relationship instead of one-to-one

Tags: php, orm, laravel

I'm having a tedious problem with Laravel's ORM.

I have a model with multiple relationships, like this:

```
class Pages extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array('id','config_id');

    public function template()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Templates', 'templates_id');
    }

    public function updateUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Users', 'updated_by');
    }
```

Now I can access the template related item in a simple way, like this:

```
$this->template->name;
```

And it works out of the bat, because Laravel's ORM assumes it is a one-to-one relationship and internally calls the first() method.

But when I try the same with updateUser it fails, returning an error, saying that it can't call name on a non-object.

But if I try this:

```
$this->updateUser()->first()->name;
```

it works, but it doesn't feel right to me.

So my question is, how Laravel's ORM decide if a relationship defined with belongsTo() is one-to-one or one-to-many? Is there a way to force a needed behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: are you using `hasOne()` to set the relationship elsewhere? and have you read the [documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-one)?

Comment: Yes, I've read the docs. I didn't use hasOne() elsewhere because a single user may be the updater of many pages, it's a one-to-many relationship from a user perspective, but one-to-one from a page's one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the relationship. You can define 'different' relationships on the perspective.

The `->belongsTo()` function is an inverse function - but you havent defined anything on the users table - so it is wrongly assuming the inverse is one-to-many.

Just add this to your users class:

```
class Users extends Eloquent {

    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Pages');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it seems that I was missing a piece, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: sorry, i don't get your answer... does it mean i need to always define the inverse of the relationship for it to work? what if i don't want to model the relationship from the other model?